# "in calce" è complemento di luogo non figurato?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

[Treccani dice che "in calce" è una locuzione avverbiale](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/calce1/), ma perché? Non è una risposta alla domanda "*Dove* metto la firma?" e, quindi, un complemento di luogo? Oltretutto, significando davvero una posizione sul foglio di carta, direi un complemento di luogo non figurato. Dove sbaglio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temo che tu stia confondendo un po' la cosiddetta analisi grammaticale (aggettivo, avverbio, voce del verbo X...) con quella logica (soggetto, complementi etc.). In genere sul dizionario trovi la categoria del primo tipo. Dirà che “casa” è un nome: se poi in una certa frase compare come soggetto, complemento oggetto o in un altro complemento, dipende dal contesto.

Nel nostro caso, sì, un avverbio (o una locuzione avverbiale) può benissimo essere un complemento di luogo: a “Dove metto la firma?” si può per esempio rispondere “Ovunque”, “Quaggiù”, “Dietro”, “In fondo” etc., e sono tutti avverbi o locuzioni avverbiali.